# SQL statement with two not ins

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables: `Documents` and `DocumentAttributes`.

- `Document` with relevant columns `DocID`, `DelFlag`
- `DocumentAttributes`: `DocID`, `aID`, `aValue`

Now I want all DocIDs and aValues with following restriction:

```
SELECT 
    [o1].[docid]
  , [o1].[aValue]
FROM [DocumentAttributes] [o1]
WHERE [o1].[aID] = 9
      AND [o1].[DocID] >= 2356
      AND [o1].[DocID] < 90000000
      AND [o1].[DocID] NOT IN
       (
          SELECT 
             [o].[DocID]
          FROM [DocumentAttributes] [o]
          WHERE [o].[aID] = 2
       )
     AND [o1].[DocID] IN
       (
          SELECT 
             [d].[DocID]
          FROM [DOCUMENTS] [d]
          WHERE [d].[DELFLAG] != 2
       );
```

So I want all IDs where Documents have no Attribute with AttributeID = 2 and which are not marked as Deleted.

The SQL statement above works, but it's too slow since I have about 1kk documents with each having about 10 Attributes at least.

The 3 selects themselves cost less than 1 second, so the "not in" is the problem I guess.

Does anyone have an idea how to make it faster?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are several techniques, some of which are RDBMS specific and some that are not.  Some that come to mind are the `minus` or `except` keywords, `not exists`, and `left joins`.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: its an oracle DB

Comment: That is invalid SQL for Oracle. Are you sure you are using Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-write the `not in` as `left join`:

```
select o1.docid, o1.aValue
from DocumentAttributes o1 
left join DocumentAttributes o on o1.DocID = o.DocID and o.aID = 2
where o1.aID = 9 and o1.DocID >= 2356 and o1.DocID < 90000000
  and o.DocID is null
and o1.DocID in (
    select d.DocID 
    from DOCUMENTS d
    where d.DELFLAG != 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle supports the `minus` keyword.  That means you can replace this sort of thing

```
where myField not in (
select someField
from etc
)
```

with this sort of thing.

```
where myField in (
select someField
from wherever
where they are available
minus
select someField
from the same tables
where I want to exclude them
)
```

I suggest trying both this and the left join method to see which performs better.

Answer (score 0):

Subselects from 'not in' statements are executed for every row, so maybe thats one of your cause.